# Unit Testing CorrelationId with Rebus

Tags: rebus

So assuming I have a `Handler` that looks like this:

```
public async Task Handle(Message message)
{
    Guid correlationId = GetCorrelationId();

    var newMessage = new MessageReceived
    {
        horse = message.Horse,
        correlationId = correlationId
    };
}

private static Guid GetCorrelationId()
{
    if (!MessageContext.Current.Headers.TryGetValue("rbs2-corr-id", out string correlationId))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    if (!Guid.TryParse(correlationId, out Guid correlationIdGuid))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    return correlationIdGuid;
}
```

How would I go about unit testing this? I currently have a (faulty, obviously) test where I just set up a `MessageReceived` object and passes it on to `Handle`, but of course it fails at `GetCorrelationId` since there is no actual `MessageContext`. Would I have to set up a `FakeBus` and use that somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing the current `IMessageContext` via the static `MessageContext.Current` property, you should inject it into the constructor of your handler like this:

```
public class MyHandler : IHandleMessages<Message>
{
    public MyHandler(IMessageContext messageContext)
    {
        this.messageContext = messageContext;
    }

    public async Task Handle(Message message)
    {
        Guid correlationId = GetCorrelationId(messageContext);

        var newMessage = new MessageReceived
        {
            horse = message.Horse,
            correlationId = correlationId
        };
    }

    static Guid GetCorrelationId(IMessageContext messageContext)
    {
        if (!messageContext.Headers.TryGetValue("rbs2-corr-id", out string correlationId))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        if (!Guid.TryParse(correlationId, out Guid correlationIdGuid))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        return correlationIdGuid;
    }
}
```

That will make it easy for you to implement a fake message context to inject during testing :)